# LWJGL Movement on Z axis object does not zoom

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, axis

I made myself a little application where I am trying to move with w, s, a, d so I coded the following code

```
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_W, getWindowID())) {
        glTranslated(0, 0, 10);
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(GLFW.GLFW_KEY_S, getWindowID())) {
        glTranslated(0, 0, -10);
    }
```

The class Keyboard works fine the problem is that when I move on the z axis it does not zoom as one would expect and when I hold it for longer teh object just disapears (because of the render distance). My init code for opengl:

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity(); // Resets any previous projection matrices
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: With orthographic projection objects have the same size regardless of the camera distance.

Comment: @BDL so how can I change this size without the gluPerspective method since it should not be used anymore ?

Comment: [`glFrustum`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml) is the perspective equivalent to `glOrtho`. Btw.: gluPerspective itself is not the problem. In OpenGL Core Profile, which should be used today, there is not matrix stack at all, so glOrtho/glFrustum/glMatrixMode all should not be used anymore.

Comment: @BDL so what should I use instead of theese methods?

Comment: In core profile you have to use uniforms in the shader where the matrices are passed in. On applications side you can use any math library you want (glm for example)